# Has anyone managed to install Office Webapps on SharePoint 2010, on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, sharepoint, windows-server-2008-r2

I've installed SharePoint 2010 as a development environment on my Windows 7 x64 environment ([notes here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869(office.14).aspx)) and would like to install Office Web Apps onto it also.

However, when trying to install (following [this link](http://merill.net/2009/11/installing-office-web-apps-on-windows-7/)), I get an error saying that Web roles aren't installed.

The error message in the log file is:

```
Start C:\Windows\system32\ServerManagerCmd.exe -whatif -inputpath C:\Users\nickh\AppData\Local\Temp\PRE1.tmp.XML
Error: Failed to start process for file: C:\Windows\system32\ServerManagerCmd.exe arguments: -whatif -inputpath C:\Users\nickh\AppData\Local\Temp\PRE1.tmp.XML ErrorCode: 2(0x2).
```

Which is effectively saying that ServerManagerCmd is not found. It isn't on my machine as it is [deprecated](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731774.aspx) and replaced by Powershell functions, but is on Server 2008 R2. I've tried copying that over and it just fails to run.

Is there a way to get Office WebApps installed on Win7 ? 
Is there a way to get a working version of ServerManagerCmd.exe on a Windows 7 x64 environment ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workaround: you need to emulate the work of ServerManagerCmd.

1. With Visual Studio create a simple console application with the name *ServerManagerCmd*
2. Add just 1 code string:

   ```
   System.Environment.ExitCode = 1003;
   ```
3. Compile and copy to `C:\Windows\System32`
4. Run setup again

Comment: I'll try that. Great suggestion though!

Comment: Sadly, no joy. That gives me 'Windows Server 2008 Features or Role Services check failed.'

Comment: Worked for me, followed instructions here: http://myriadtech.com.au/blog/James/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=50 which includes a link to a ServerManagerCmd.exe

Answer (score 0):

I very much doubt that you could get this to work.  SharePoint is probably very dependent on features and tools only available and designed to run on Server 2008.

I believe Microsoft has expressed that they would like the core parts of their server and desktop operating systems to be more similar, but even with these latest 2 releases, I don't believe they are there yet.  Their [system requirements for SharePoint 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485(office.14).aspx) are very specific, especially for a Microsoft product which usually operates on a wide variety of their platforms.

Comment: As I said in my question, Microsoft have a process installing SharePoint on Windows 7, which I followed (there's a link in the question).

I'm just wanting to install Office Web Apps onto it.

Thanks anyway.